# how to count the number of lines in a text file that start with a date

Tags: regex, bash, clearcase, wc

I have a file that has the content as

```
2004-10-07     cva        create file ...
2003-11-11     cva        create version ...
2003-11-11     cva        create version ...
2003-11-11     cva        create branch ...
```

now I want to count the number of lines that start with date in this particular file.
How can I do that

if I use `wc -l <file.txt>`
it gives me total number of lines(5 in my case whereas I want is count should be 4)

Comment: `grep "[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}" filename | wc -l` should give number of lines for this particular format. However, it can be better with awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
2004-10-07     cva        create file ...
no date
2003-11-11     cva        create version ...
no date
2003-11-11     cva        create version ...
no date
2003-11-11     cva        create branch ...
```

First figure out how to run a regex on each line of the file. Suppose you use `sed` since it is fairly standard and fast. You could also use `awk`, `grep`, `bash`, `perl`

Here is a `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -nE '/^[12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/p' file
2004-10-07     cva        create file ...
2003-11-11     cva        create version ...
2003-11-11     cva        create version ...
2003-11-11     cva        create branch ...
```

Then pipe that to `wc`:

```
$ sed -nE '/^[12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/p' file | wc -l
      4
```

Or, you can use the same pattern in `awk` and not need to use `wc`:

```
$ awk '/^[12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{lc++} END{ print lc }' file
4
```

Or if you wanted the count of each date:

```
$ awk '/^[12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{cnt[$1]++} END{ for (e in cnt) print e, cnt[e] }' file
2003-11-11 3
2004-10-07 1
```

Or, same pattern, with `grep`:

```
$ grep -cE '^[12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' file
4
```

---

(Note: it is unclear if your date format is `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-DD-MM` You can make the pattern more specific if this is known. )

Comment: How can I print the number for each date individually not the total lines that start with a date

Comment: Do you mean the each date is counted? Like so: `2003-11-11 3, 2004-10-07 1`? See edit...

Comment: Yes. I found the command that creates a csv file with the result date, count sed -n 's/\(^[^ ]*\).*/\1/p' history.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2","$1}' > output.csv

Answer (score 0):

An easy and simple way with: **Perl**

**your file**

```
2004-10-07     cva 
2004-10-04             
anything
2004-10-07     cva 
anything
2004-10-07     cva 
2004-10-07     cva
```

**you need**
`perl -lne ' ++$n if /^\d+-\d+-\d+/; print $n' your-file`

**output**

```
1  
2  
2  
3  
3  
4  
5
```

---

**Count and only print sum**
`perl -lne ' ++$n if /^\d+-\d+-\d+/ ;END{ print $n}' your-file`

**output**
`5`

---

**with egrep**  `-c` count the match numbers
`cat your-file | egrep -c '^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+'`

**output**
`5`

Comment: How can I enhance this by printing the date with the number in the same line separated by comma "," ?